# Init call on Slick slider PageBuilder not working

Tags: magento2, slider, page-builder, slick

for the Slick slider of the Slider Banner PageBuilder module, I am trying to add an 'init' call, so I can run a function on initialization of the slider. First I tried adding a new js file called widget-hero.js on this path:

Example/PageBuilderExtensionSlider/view/base/web/js/content-type/slider/appearance/default/widget-hero.js

in which I have this code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config, element) {

        var $element = $(element);

        console.log('from Example/PageBuilderExtensionSlider/view/base/web/js/content-type/slider/appearance/default/widget-hero.js');

        console.log($element);

        $element.on('init', function(slick) {
            console.log('Slick Init from widget-hero.js');
        });

    };
});
```

It normally works and console logs 'Slick Init from widget-hero.js' , but there are times when it doesn't work, so, I reckon
sometimes the file gets read while the slider hasn't been initialized yet.

Then I tried editing the file that initializes the Slick slider by copying to this path:

Example/PageBuilderExtensionSlider/view/base/web/js/content-type/slider/appearance/default/widget.js

On that files I have this code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_PageBuilder/js/events',
    'slick'
], function ($, events) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config, sliderElement) {
        var $element = $(sliderElement);

        /**
         * Prevent each slick slider from being initialized more than once which could throw an error.
         */
        if ($element.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
            $element.slick('unslick');
        }

        $element.slick({
            autoplay: $element.data('autoplay'),
            autoplaySpeed: $element.data('autoplay-speed') || 0,
            fade: $element.data('fade'),
            infinite: $element.data('is-infinite'),
            arrows: $element.data('show-arrows'),
            dots: $element.data('show-dots')
        });

        // Redraw slide after content type gets redrawn
        events.on('contentType:redrawAfter', function (args) {
            if ($element.closest(args.element).length) {
                $element.slick('setPosition');
            }
        });

        console.log('from Example/PageBuilderExtensionSlider/view/base/web/js/content-type/slider/appearance/default/widget.js');

        console.log($element);

        $element.on('init', function(slick) {
            console.log('Slick Init from widget.js');
        });
    };
});
```

But the init call doesn't work here, I do get the console log of these lines 
console.log('from Example/PageBuilderExtensionSlider/view/base/web/js/content-type/slider/appearance/default/widget.js');
console.log($element);

But I am not getting console.log('Slick Init from widget.js');

Suming up, init is not working from the file where we initialize the slick slider, any idea why this could be happening?

My console log: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a lot like you're experiencing a [race condition](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/race-condition) with the default and `widget-hero.js` widgets. Most likely what's happening is the default widget is being called first and Slick is initialized before your event handler is registered.

You'll want to ensure you register your `on` event handler before the call `.slick()`, as the initialization of Slick could happen before your code can register the event. In your second example you should move the event registration up:

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_PageBuilder/js/events',
    'slick'
], function ($, events) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config, sliderElement) {
        var $element = $(sliderElement);

        /**
         * Prevent each slick slider from being initialized more than once which could throw an error.
         */
        if ($element.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
            $element.slick('unslick');
        }

        $element.on('init', function(slick) {
            console.log('Slick Init from widget.js');
        });

        $element.slick({
            autoplay: $element.data('autoplay'),
            autoplaySpeed: $element.data('autoplay-speed') || 0,
            fade: $element.data('fade'),
            infinite: $element.data('is-infinite'),
            arrows: $element.data('show-arrows'),
            dots: $element.data('show-dots')
        });

        // Redraw slide after content type gets redrawn
        events.on('contentType:redrawAfter', function (args) {
            if ($element.closest(args.element).length) {
                $element.slick('setPosition');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Within Page Builder we do not yet have a method of declaring in which order the store front widgets should load. If you're adding a new appearance that also needs to initialize Slick you should follow the same principle as shown above, registering your event before you initialize.